# Conky on root desktop doesn't show config file changes

Tags: conky

**Summary:**

I recently installed Crunchbang and want to change the color of Conky, which is installed by default and shows system status info on the desktop. However, changing the config settings doesn't seem to make a difference, even when I manually restart conky.

**Details:**

I found two config files:

```
/etc/conky/conky.conf

/etc/conky/conky_no_x11.conf
```

They have color settings. If I change the settings and run

```
$ conky
```

then a terminal-looking panel appears that DOES reflect my changes. I noticed that in order to refresh the desktop Conky, not this terminal-looking Conky, I have to do

```
$ sudo killall conky
$ sudo conky -q
```

Killing it makes Conky disappear off the desktop. Starting it again as root makes it reappear on the desktop. But none of changes I make to the config files show up in the "root desktop" Conky, only when I run it as a "subsystem" Conky.

Please help me understand what is going on, and what I am missing.

Comment: Could you please [edit] and clarify a little? What do you mean by "root desktop"? Are you logging into the GUI as root? If so, why `sudo`? Is there a `~/.conkyrc` file? Is there a `/root/.conkyrc` file? Which config file are you editing, `/etc/conky/conky.conf`?

Comment: "Root desktop" is a term that conky uses in the documentation to refer to the GUI desktop and not a background forked process that runs an instance of Conky. The ~/.conkyrc file existed. I edited that file and ran the script /usr/bin/conkywonky to refresh the "desktop" instance of conky. If you post your response as an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Also worth noting that ~/.conkyrc was a hidden file

Comment: I remember that conky has some auto reload boolean in the config file, but I don't remember its name. Check out the conky configuration reference.

Comment: @psimon Yes you are right, after a while I realized that after I wrote changes to the config file, the changes were automatically updated on the desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default configuration file for conky is `~/.conkyrc`. This follows classic *nix convention that wants configuration files to be hidden (dot files) in `~/`.

If that file exists, it will be read when you launch conky and the files in `/etc` will be ignored as you have seen. You can override the default with the `-c` flag (at least in conky 1.9.0):

```
   -c | --config= FILE
          Config file to load instead of $HOME/.conkyrc
```

Answer (score 0):

The desktop, while it appears behind all the user's windows, is not a "root desktop". It's your desktop, the desktop of the user. `conky` opens in a terminal when you run it from a terminal. Using "sudo" doesn't move it to the desktop. It runs conky as root user. But what you changed are the preferences for a simple user. Even if you changed the preferences in `/etc`. Preferences for the root user would be in /root.
On Linux Mint 19 (based on Ubuntu, like Crunchbang originally), running `conky` from the Alt+F2 launcher opens it on the desktop. Changes in `/etc/conky` are read correctly.